# EF Core DataSets on DbContext are all null despite data being in the database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a project (this is a play project so don't freak out about security here), [Found Here](https://github.com/mrlst16/AuthHub) on branch AUT-3

When I go through and debug, all of my data is null in the model.  Meaning that the data sets themselves are null.

[image]
I am using SQL Server although I tried with postgresql as well.  This is on my local machine for right now.

I have successfully added the migrations, updated the database and verified that the data was added.

[image]

I have tried switching database and providers (postgresql to sql server). I have even tried to start a new context, but no dice. The only thing I haven't tried is sacrificing a lamb to the coding gods.

Any advice is much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your code of `DbContext` and how you use it here (formatted), instead of an image.

Comment: You're missing a public setter for the `DbSet<Foo>` properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a public setter for DbSet in EF.

In your `AuthHubContext.cs`, change

```
public DbSet<User> Users;
```

to

```
public DbSet<User> Users {get; set;}
```

Comment: Dude! You saved the day! I knew it was something dumb! THank you and Thank you Interwebs!